# MySQL syntax error writing to database

Tags: php, mysql

I have an error when I try to write to the database.

Error message (I tested it with some values...):

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values(Digger, 45_456, 645_645, 6_6, 456_456, 456_45, ' at line 3

My code:

```
Mysql_query("INSERT INTO 
        ".$balicky_table." 
        values(".$name.",     <-line 3
        ".$id1."_".$kus1.", 
        ".$id2."_".$kus2.", 
        ".$id3."_".$kus3.", 
        ".$id4."_".$kus4.", 
        ".$id5."_".$kus5.", 
        ".$id6."_".$kus6.", 
        ".$id7."_".$kus7.", 
        ".$id8."_".$kus8.", 
        ".$id9."_".$kus9.", 
        ".$id10."_".$kus10.", 
        ".$id11."_".$kus11.", 
        ".$id12."_".$kus12.", 
        ".$cost.")", $SpojenieWeb) or die(mysql_error());
```

In database I have type Varchar(100)

Comment: You need to wrap each value in quotes. That said, this code is open to SQL injection if any of those variables come from external sources.

Comment: For text data need use single quotes, like this `values('".$name."', `

Comment: Could you tell use what it stored in $balicky_table, you are missing quotes for sure but you also have an error before in columns

Comment: This all looks very, very wrong. Have you read up on normalization?

Answer (score 1):

Digger is a string so needs quotes: `values('".$name."',`.

Comment: Dont work I add quotes:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values('Digger', 45_456, 645_645, 6_6, 456_456, 456_45,' at line 3

Comment: ok all values are quotes - dont work
In database I have columns with varchar(110)
And names are 1. name 2. Item_1 3. Item_2 ..... Item_12 and cost

Comment: I'd suggest updating your question accordingly, with the new error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes: see here:

```
Mysql_query("INSERT INTO 
        ".$balicky_table." 
        values('".$name."',    
        '".$id1."_".$kus1."', 
        '".$id2."_".$kus2."', 
        '".$id3."_".$kus3."', 
        '".$id4."_".$kus4."', 
        '".$id5."_".$kus5."', 
        '".$id6."_".$kus6."', 
        '".$id7."_".$kus7."', 
        ''".$id8."_".$kus8."', 
        '".$id9."_".$kus9."', 
        '".$id10."_".$kus10."', 
        '".$id11."_".$kus11."', 
        '".$id12."_".$kus12."', 
        '".$cost."')", $SpojenieWeb) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to qoute the data. That is the problem

Check this:

```
"INSERT INTO 
    ".$balicky_table." 
    values('".$name."',
    '".$id1."_".$kus1."', 
    '".$id2."_".$kus2."', 
    '".$id3."_".$kus3."', 
    '".$id4."_".$kus4."', 
    '".$id5."_".$kus5."', 
    '".$id6."_".$kus6."', 
    '".$id7."_".$kus7."', 
    '".$id8."_".$kus8."', 
    '".$id9."_".$kus9."', 
    '".$id10."_".$kus10."', 
    '".$id11."_".$kus11."', 
    '".$id12."_".$kus12."', 
    '".$cost."')", $SpojenieWeb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi it seems like the value over here are strings. As you concetnate them using '_' . String needs to be wrapped with quote. As you are using Double quote for your php you can wrap using single quote single quote.

```
"INSERT INTO 
  ".$balicky_table." 
  values('".$name."',
  '".$id1."_".$kus1."', 
  .......
```

For all of them.